# textbox only allow a-z 0-9 and . , + - and $

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I am struggling to make this happen. I have a text box 
and in this textbox I only allow these charcode.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789
and only these symbols +-.,$
```

I am only using pure javascript and onkeydown
but using onkeydown I cannot detect the keypress. for example when the user is pressing shift + 5 ... I get keycode 16 and keycode 53 , where I only looking for keycode 37
. I am testing this using IE11

this is what I have

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    document.forms[0].addEventListener("input", function (e) {
      var input = this.children[0];
      var not = input.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+/g);
      if (not) {
          not.forEach(function (text) {
              input.value = input.value.replace(text, "")
          })
      }
  })
</script> 
'this is a dynamic textbox
Dim txtDesc As New TextBox
txtDesc.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return isAllowed(event)")
```

The above code works fine only for Chrome and Firefox.

what do I have to do to get the effect of onkeypress on IE11?
I tried onkeypress on IE11 and it is not firing.

My solution has to work on all Chrome, FF and IE11 if possible.

thank you

[image]

Comment: Simplest approach would be to use `input` element , `pattern` attribute

Comment: thanks I'll try this [A-Za-z0-9+-.,$]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `RegExp` `[a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+`

```js
document.forms["form"].addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var input = this.querySelector("input[name=input]");
  var not = input.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+/g);
  if (not) {
    not.forEach(function(text) {
      input.value = input.value.replace(text, "")
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input name="input" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: this is an issue. I will get calls from users asking why .. I rather the system stripped unwanted characters if possible

Comment: _"I rather the system stripped unwanted characters if possible "_ See updated post; `RegExp` at `.match()` checks if a character is not within character class

Comment: Any idea why I get Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference. updated my code in the original post

Comment: You probably do not have a `form` element within `html` ? `this.children[0]` references first element within a `form`. Have not tried `vb.net` or `asp.net` . Will update post to provide `name` attributes for `form` , `input` elements; see updated post

Comment: thanks moving the script to at the end after body seems to make it work. will test some more.. Thank you!

Comment: complains about input.value.match :( .. if this help my dynamic textbox ID is always prefix with "Desc_"  can it only check if the id starts with "Desc_"

Comment: I think var input = this.children[0]; is not getting the right object ... input.value says undefined.

Comment: _"complains about input.value.match"_ Error logged ? If yes, what is error ?

Comment: input.value.match says JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'match' of undefined or null reference

Comment: When is this error logged ? Within `input` handler ?

Comment: var not = input.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+/g);  <-- error.

Comment: oopssI notice you change this.children[0] to this.children["input"] .. <-- testing nit now

Comment: OK i get a different error now on the same row. 
 
var not = input.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+/g); <-- JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Not certain how an error is generated from `var not = input.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.+,$-]+/g);` ? Again, have not tried `vb.net` or `asp.net` . At an `html` document where `javascript` is enabled, should not return an error. Will change `children` to `querySelector` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children ; see updated post

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XOxq2.jpg I take a screenshot the whole aspx file. Notice when I hover on input it says undefined  .. basic file with nothing . weird

Comment: `children` is not available in ie, safari; adjusted to `.querySelector()` , see updated post

Comment: hooorayy!!.. works in my basic ASPX page. testing in my full page now.thank you!

Comment: uh no.. on the other aspx page var input = this.querySelector("input[name=input]"); returns NULL. thus not working . argh ..

Comment: I think I know why. since the input element is dynamically created the name is random but always prefix with "desc_"   let me try just input ... I wonder if it will work since there are 10  - 30 input element

Comment: Try `this.querySelector("input[name^=desc_]")`

Comment: Man, I appreciate your time.. That is it! thank you so much for spending the time looking into this.